# Run a docker image on Windows results in "oci runtime error: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH."

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

I'm running Docker on Windows ("Docker Toolbox", not "Docker for Windows").

I've built an image with a rails app inside. It works properly on my Mac OS but stucks on production on Windows.

Using Docker 1.12 and docker-machine 0.8.0 on both machines.

When I create a machine and try to run the container from image, I do:

```
docker run -it myRepo:myTag bash
```

which opens me a interactive terminal on Mac OS, but Windows 7 and Windows Server 2011 are both responding with:

> "Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "bash":
>   executable file not found in $PATH."

I use the **MINGW64** shell via the **Docker Quickstart Terminal** but the old **cmd.exe** returns the same.

Can anybody help me with this issue? I've tried several hours to find a solution but there are too few answers for Windows.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have to install MSYS2 (MinGW64 is maybe OK if it has a shell), then provide the path to `bash.exe` in your windows system or user path.

Answer (score 1):

I also use Windows 7 with MINGW64. Here is what I get using `nginx` as example:

```
  $docker run -it nginx bash
  cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
```

I don't think you can open a tty using MINGW64.

You can try:

```
  $docker run -i nginx bash
  ls
  bin
  ...
```

You will so no prompt or any indication you are inside the container. Just run `ls` and it should work inside your container.

Another option is to try to use `winpty` for the tty:

```
  $ winpty docker run -it myRepo:myTag bash
  root@644f59e6f818:/#
```

Have you tried?

```
  $ winpty docker run -it myRepo:myTag /bin/bash
```

I haven't got the problem you are mentioning but I have seen it before when I was mapping volumes.

If you are mapping volumes using MINGW64, you will need to add an extra `/` before the local mapping. For example:

```
   docker run -p 8080:80 -v "/$PWD":/var/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Let me know your findings.

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution. Will give it a try and give you feedback.